# Profile WebGL page on Android

Tags: javascript, android, performance, profiling, webgl

How can I profile a 3D web page (WebGL) on Android? I was able to successfully [connect remotely](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) using Google Chrome Developer Tools and I can see the JavaScript time spent, but it seems the page performance is limited not by the script itself, but someplace else (I assume it is the rendering):

[image: Chrome Dev Tools screenshot]

Is there any way I could e.g. learn why is [Three.js Minecraft](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_minecraft) example lot slower than the [Three.js Terrain](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=terrain#webgl_geometry_terrain)?

I was unable to find any tool which would show me even basic device statistics, like GPU load. The [Android developer GPU Profiling tools (on screen graph)](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/inspect-gpu-rendering) is not showing any activity when in Google Chrome (I have tried it works fine while in games).

Comment: I don't know how to run the Android GPU tools but as far as the two samples go the minecraft one is using 2 lights and a MeshLambertMaterial. The Terrain one is using no lights and a MeshBasicMaterial. 2 lights are slower than none. I'm surprised there's a noticable difference in perf on a modern phone. Like I tried an iPhone6+ and both run at 60fps. But of course different phones have different GPUs.

Comment: One arguable issue with almost all samples on the three.js site is they set the resolution to match the phone which is way too high for perf.  Remove the line `renderer.setPixelRatio` and perf could jump as high as 9x and look the same at a glance.

Comment: "I'm surprised there's a noticable difference in perf on a modern phone" Just for information: I am not running it on a modern phone, I am testing it on a Yoga Tablet. I do not expect any stellar performance, but I expect to achieve an interactive frame rate.